# iptables / forward request to specific IP to wifi network

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I'm struggling with the Linux tool "iptables".
Following situation:
I have a RaspberryPi running with HASS (Home Assistant) connected via ethernet.
Now I want to add my inverter to home assistant, but this needs to be done by using his own WiFi network. So I need to forward requests to IP 11.11.11.1 (only this IP, not all trafic) to the wifi network.

Is that doable with iptables? Meaning defining a rule which says "target is 11.11.11.1, so lets put this to the wifi network".

I'm actually not sure whether iptables can do that or not. I read soming about nginx, but not sure how this would work.

Comment: I tried now following commant
"iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -p tcp --destination 11.11.11.1"

seems that works somehow. Still need to test. will write some updates later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -p tcp --destination 11.11.11.1
```

That command did the trick. Now all TCP requests to 11.11.11.1 are forwarded to Wifi (wlan0) interface.

If someone sees any mistakes in that, please reply as I'm not really familiar with networks settings and Linux commands. Thx.